# (Reached end of current page, get the next page...,# Parse the response payload) Twitter error response: status code = 400

Tags: python, tweepy

my code crawling data

```py
import tweepy
import csv
import pandas as pd
consumer_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
consumer_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
access_token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
access_token_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)

csvFile = open('ua.csv','a')
svWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=input("Masukan Keyword"),count=100,
                            lang="en",
                            since="2019-06-01").items():
    print (tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
```

TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 400

error in console
code run in jupyterLab console

in console there  error from tweepy package

## Reached end of current page, get the next page...

## Parse the response payload